# Mongodb join two collections giving duplicate results

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

```
  def get(self):
      res  = json.loads(dumps( 
                  self.devices_col.aggregate([
                      {"$lookup":  {
                          "from": "participants",
                          "localField": "_id.docgroupid",
                          "foreignField": "device_id",
                          "as": "participants"
                          }
                      },
                      {
                          "$unwind": "$participants"
                      }
                  ])
       ))
      return res
```

participants document

```
      {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5f7230502930714468ed892c"),
        "hash" : "83a84e8bf170114cffcc3b1e178d6468",
        "name" : "BOMW0000029529",
        "persona_id" : "i123",
        "command" : "start",
        "va_info" : [
            {
                "device_id" : "5f722a742930714468ed8929",
                "automation_config" : "",
                "status" : "false",
                "remote_path" : "/datadrive/gatewayfolder",
                "version" : "1.3.0.9",
                "latest_va_version" : "1.3.1.2",
                "version_updated_on" : "",
                "latest_va_build_number" : "20200525",
                "last_connected_on" : "02/08/2020 11:25:55",
                "last_seen_on" : "02/08/2020 11:25:55",
                "last_activity_processed_on" : "02/07/2020 11:25:55"
            }
        ],
        "inclusions" : [
            "myfinancewnscom",
            "OUTLOOK",
            "jp2launcher",
            "EXCEL"
        ],
        "created_by" : "",
        "created_on" : "",
        "modified_by" : "",
        "modified_on" : ""
      }
```

devices document

```
              {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5f722a742930714468ed8929"),
        "name" : "",
        "unique_id" : "u168381",
        "os" : {
            "version" : "6.2.9200.0",
            "name" : "Microsoft Windows 10 Home",
            "locale" : {
                "geo_location" : null,
                "time_zone" : "IST",
                "day_light_saving_support" : false
            },
            "culture" : {
                "name" : "en-US",
                "LCID" : "1032",
                "language" : "English (United States)"
            },
            "browser" : [
                {
                    "name" : "IE",
                    "value" : "9.11.17763.0"
                },
                {
                    "name" : "Chrome",
                    "value" : "84.0.4147.105"
                },
                {
                    "name" : "Firefox",
                    "value" : "Not Found"
                }
            ]
        },
        "created_by" : "",
        "created_on" : "",
        "modified_by" : "",
        "modified_on" : ISODate("2020-07-21T06:08:50.876Z")
    }
```

Here is my data.

Here is my piece of python code. i am using pymongo client to make query from mongodb
In above code i am trying to join two collection (devices and participants) with device_id (Which is inside participants)
collections.

I have only two records in each collections.

But, output giving me 4 result.
Two duplicate records it is giving.

Please have a look where i am making wrong.

Comment: Can we see the documents?

Comment: It's all about data. I **guess** it matches 2x2 docs and if you show how they look like I can tell you what's happening precisely

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't doubles, it multiplies: number of devices * number of participants.

In your pipeline you join the collections as:

```
                 {"$lookup":  {
                      "from": "participants",
                      "localField": "_id.docgroupid",
                      "foreignField": "device_id",
                      "as": "participants"
                      }
                  }
```

There is no `_id.docgroupid` field in devices and there are no `device_id` field in participants so it makes a perfect match of each participant to each device.

After the lookup stage the `participants` field hold whole `participants` collection. When you unwind it you see the same parent document with each single participant. Even tho the _id values of the documents are the same they are not identical duplicates and differ by participants field.

Comment: If i need to join one more collection shall i add another foreignField or how it is ?

Comment: No, you add one more `$lookup` stage. Lookup is strictly between 2 collections.

Comment: device_id is inside the array how it is working ? So giving all participants inside the devices

Comment: Sorry mate, I don't follow. How what is working? You are using `"foreignField": "device_id",` in your lookup. It tells mongo to link documents by value of `device_id` field on the top level, not anywhere in sub-docs.

Comment: How can we check which is inside the array ?